# Prevent the entity model from loading the local instance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, connection-string, ef-database-first

I am using *Database First*. I have overridden my `DbContext` class so that it does not read the connection string from the local instance of the model:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities(string cs)
        : base("name=Entities")
    {
    }
}
```

The `cs` value is supposed to be used as connection string.

In my `App.config` I removed the values for connection string in both places that I have marked with `XXX`.

```
<connectionStrings><add name="Entities" connectionString="XXX" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings><userSettings>
    <Prospect.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="ConnectionString" serializeAs="String">
        <value>XXX</value>
      </setting>
    </Prospect.Properties.Settings>
  </userSettings>
```

When I remove these values, I see that the program is still trying to use the local instance for my *EntityModel* which is `NULL` and therefore throws and exception.

How can I tell my model to always ignore the local instance and read the connection string from the `cs` value that I keep in .ini file ?

Answer (score 2):

Just pass cs to base context:

```
public partial class Entities : DbContext
{
    public Entities(string cs)
        : base(cs)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that, but now I get an Exception on my `OnModelCreating` event that says: "The context is being used in Code First mode with code that was generated from an EDMX file for either Database First or Model First development.  This will not work correctly. To fix this problem do not remove the line of code that throws this exception..." FYI I am using Database First

Comment: in this case you cannot do what you want. Try to change to codefirst approach, or get connection string from app.config